# How to get products list by category ID?

Tags: category, collection, products, product-collection, magento-1

How can I get a products list by category ID? I need to display them with products name or ID.

My code so far:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($currentctid)
                    ->getCollection() 
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
                    ->joinTable('pdp/productstatus', 'product_id=entity_id', array('*'));
```

Comment: $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                             ->getCollection()
                             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $currentctid));

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. It retrieves the active category. If that is not set it gets the first category the product is assigned to. The collection holds all products for that category

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if (empty($category)) {
   $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
   $categoryId = reset($product->getCategoryIds());
   $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
}

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Comment: @Ramesh if it worked for you please accept the answer :)

Comment: @Ramesh can you accept this as the answer? It has a check under the vote buttons